# PHP - How to use SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

Trying to grab RSS Feeds using the `SimpleXMLElement`, but I'm not fully understanding how to do this.  My code is as follows:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    var_dump($x);

}

getFeed("http://feedproxy.google.com/themeforest");
```

It outputs the following:

> object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["HEAD"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2
>   (1) { ["TITLE"]=> string(17) "Moved Permanently" } ["BODY"]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (3) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) {
>   ["BGCOLOR"]=> string(7) "#FFFFFF" ["TEXT"]=> string(7) "#000000" }
>   ["H1"]=> string(17) "Moved Permanently" ["A"]=> string(4) "here" } }

I have tried changing my code above to this, but than it outputs NOTHING and I get a foreach error:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);

    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    echo '
        <ul>';

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo '
        <li>
          <a href="' . $entry->link . '" title="' . $entry->title . '">' . $entry->title . '</a>
        </li>';
    }

    echo '
        </ul>';

}

getFeed("http://feedproxy.google.com/themeforest");
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be accessed like an object. Please read the first example here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Comment: I am trying to create a setup where the user types in the URL to the RSS feed, and it automatically outputs the feeds information title and link into a section of their site.  How would I be able to grab this info. using children?  But more importantly, how would I be able to tell the difference between outputting normally and whether or not I need to search for children...?

Comment: Well, what does the $content look like?

Comment: OMG, the RSS Feeds URL was moved to another link, so OMG, I didn't notice this and put in the wrong RSS Feeds URL.  It works fine with the new url, which is:  `http://feeds.feedburner.com/themeforest`  Thanks, topic solved!

Comment: Just gonna give you the answer cause you actually made me realize that it was the wrong URL for the RSS feed.

Comment: Thank you Solomon - I did see that, but I thought you intentionally wanted to show to the user that the RSS feed had changed. I'm glad you worked it out. BTW, it would be nice for other readers, if you edit your question to add some advice at the end, on how you figured this out, since my answer is not very intuitive.

Comment: Well, I just put in the correct RSS Feed URL for this, which is:  `http://feeds.feedburner.com/themeforest`